# Examples of functors that preserves products but not equalizers, and vice versa.

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

What are simple examples, for student consumption, of

1. A functor which preserves products (or at least finite products) but not equalizers.
2. A functor which preserves equalizers but not products.

Ideally, it would be good to have reasonably natural examples involving reasonably familiar categories and which don't call on esoteric background knowledge!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S$ be the category of sets (and functions), and let $F$ be the functor from $S$ to $S$ that sends the empty set to itself and sends every nonempty set to a singleton (and acts on maps in the only possible way).  This preserves products, but it fails to preserve the equalizer of the two maps from a singleton to a two-element set.

For the other direction, consider the functor $G:S\to S$ that sends objects $x$ to $x\times 2$ and sends maps $f$ to $f\times 1_2$ (where $2$ means a 2-element set and $1_2$ is its identity map).  This preserves equalizers but messes up products (even the empty product 1).

Comment: Thanks! Those are just the kind of neat "entry-level" examples I was hoping for.

Comment: A homotopy theorist might call the first functor $\pi_{-1}$.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena And then your homotopy theorist might generalize to $\pi_n$ for larger values of $n$.  But, as Peter's comment suggests, I was trying to keep my answer at level appropriate for the likely  level of the students who need it.  After all, Qiaochu had already given a perfectly correct answer, but it struck me as likely to go over the students' heads.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be a left $R$-module. Tensoring with $M$ gives a cocontinuous functor $(-) \otimes_R M$ from right $R$-modules to abelian groups. It preserves equalizers iff $M$ is flat and it preserves products iff $M$ is finitely presented, so

1. Find a module which is finitely presented but not flat. For example, we can take $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Z}_2$. The corresponding functor takes an abelian group $A$ to the tensor product $A \otimes \mathbb{Z}_2$. This preserves products but it does not preserve the equalizer of the diagram $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0, 2} \mathbb{Z}$.
2. Find a module which is flat but not finitely presented. For example, we can take $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Q}$. The corresponding functor takes an abelian group $A$ to the tensor product $A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$. This preserves equalizers but it does not preserve the product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.